# Firebase subscribe to topics not working after reinstalling app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, reinstall

I made an app which was working fine until I found that after deleting and reinstalling the app it doesn't receive messages anymore that are sent to a a topic, although it does receive a message that is sent to the id-token of the app.
Does anybody know what might be the problem? Firebase or my app?

Update:
After clearing cache and data of the app it can receive notifications again. If reinstalled there's a chance of not working. I have to do some more testing, but I think it is solved by setting android:allowBackup="false" in the app manifest.

Answer (score 2):

After the uninstall and reinstall, your app on that device was assigned a new [device token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register).  According to that documentation:

> The registration token may change when:
>
> - The app deletes Instance ID
> - The app is restored on a new device
> - The user uninstalls/reinstall the app
> - The user clears app data.

That new token won't have all the same subscriptions that the old one had.  You'll have to [re-subscribe to the topics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging#subscribe_the_client_app_to_a_topic) that the user was interested in on that device.

It's not just reinstalls - your app should be ready to handle new tokens at any time, based on the criteria listed above.  The linked documentation illustrates how to listen to token changes.

Comment: The app doesn't receive messages after re-subscribing to the topics.

Comment: Strange...after more than a day the app works again like it should on my phone. Could it be that it takes time for Firebase to invalidate and validate the device again?